# How to get the target operating system in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to set a Property on which os we're targeting with the build.

I would like to know if we're targeting windows or Linux when we run these to commands.

`dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64`

or

`dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64`

the variable `$(OS)` always shows `Windows_NT`

Is there a predefined variable that will tell me whether or not were targeting Windows or Linux?

Comment: Sidenote: `OS` is an environment variable set by Windows. Thus it will always say 'Windows_NT'. MSBuild merely gives you access to it as a property, as it does with any other environment variable applicable for the MSBuild.exe process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a predefined variable for this, however, I was able to create one.

```
<Target Name="AfterPublishTarget" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <PropertyGroup>
       <IsWindows>$(PublishDir.Contains('win'))</IsWindows>
       <IsLinux>$(PublishDir.Contains('linux'))</IsLinux>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

I hope this helps others.